# Toggling Rater.js's Readonly feature

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change rater.js's readonly feature by following codes,

```
<div class="rating" data-rate-value=6></div>

// setting readonly to false
var raterOptions = {
                        max_value: 5,
                        step_size: 0.5,
                        initial_value: 0,
                        readonly: false
                    }  
$(".rating").rate(raterOptions);
   
// setting readonly to true
 raterOptions = {
                        max_value: 5,
                        step_size: 0.5,
                        initial_value: 0,
                        readonly: true
                    }

$(".rating").rate(raterOptions);
```

However it keeps first state, so not change to readonly true. Isn't this possible?

Answer (score 0):

After closer examining, mousemove and click events in browser's dev tool caught my attention. And trying unbinding them solved the problem.

```
$('.rating').unbind("click");
$('.rating').unbind('mousemove');
```